# Punctuation question: quotation marks around names in dialog?

Tags: punctuation

If you refer to a name alone and not along with a person in dialog, do you put single quotation marks around it?

E.g., "Yeah, I agree with you there. 'Jon' is pretty common, but the same could be said of 'Jeffrey,' too."

E.g., "I could go with the name, Jon, sure, but I prefer 'Jeff' instead; or maybe since my last name's Thomas I'll go with 'Tommy.'

Made up examples, but they convey what I'm iffy about fine I think. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Really I think it's perfect as in your first example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use quotations or possibly even bare, but I think the best option would be to use italics, since that's more common for when talking about words as words (in this case, it's a name as a word):

- “Yeah, I agree with you there.  *Jon* is pretty common, but the same could be said of *Jeffrey*, too”
- “I could go with the name *Jon*, sure, but I prefer *Jeff* instead; or maybe since my last name’s *Thomas*, I’ll go with *Tommy*.”

I would do the same inside or outside of quotation marks, though.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! In this case, italics aren't an option for me. I guess quotation singlets should work, even though the bare approach seems tenable to me, too. Maybe it's simply a stylistic choice?

Comment: @rr I'm inclined to say yes.  It would not surprise me at all if there were two style guides that indicated two different ways.  If italics aren't available, I'd probably go with quotes.  The first of your two sentences wouldn't jump out at me personaly as discussing names without them or other context.

Comment: "If italics aren't available, I'd probably go with quotes" indeed it's that simple